# Is it possible to pickle a QSettings object?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pickle

I realize this sounds horribly redundant, since pickle and QSettings basically achieve the same thing, but let me explain.

I have a program made up of widgets that can be docked, resized, or otherwise modified. The user wants to be able to save various states as layouts and change between these layouts. The layout is saved as a QSettings file.

To save a list of layouts, I want to pickle a dictionary of the format `{'layoutName':qSettingsFile, 'anotherName':anotherFile}`, but when I try to pickle a QSettings file I get `TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed`.

Is there a way to make this work? I could just put the contents of the QSettings file in the dictionary and forget about QSettings, but I'm hoping for an easier/shorter way.

Comment: I've gone with working the contents of the file into the dictionary for now. Turns out it wasn't as bad as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **one** settings file, and create separate groups for each layout.

The [QSettings syntax](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#section-and-key-syntax) supports hierarchical keys, so just use [beginGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#beginGroup) and [endGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#endGroup) to create named layout sections:

```
settings.beginGroup('layouts')
settings.beginGroup('layoutname1')
# set various layout values...
settings.endGroup()
settings.beginGroup('layoutname2')
# set various layout values...
settings.endGroup()
settings.endGroup()
```

Which would output a file looking like this:

```
layouts/layoutname1/value1=true
layouts/layoutname1/value2=true
...
layouts/layoutname2/value1=false
layouts/layoutname2/value2=false
...
```

Alternatively, you could use [QSettings arrays](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#beginWriteArray) to create an of indexed list of layouts.

Comment: Great answer! Unfortunately this won't work in my situation due to legacy code, but under normal circumstances this would be perfect, so I'm marking it as correct.

Comment: Wanted to add also the extra benefit of sticking with a single `QSettings` approach as opposed to writing out your own pickle is that it picks the proper platform-specific preferences location and format. On OSX, for instance, it writes plist files to the preferred user location.